# "react-native run-android" - BUILD is SUCCESSFUL but get error type 3 Error: Activity class MainActivity does not exist

Tags: android, react-native

I try to run application on android emulator but it failed.
I run `react-native run-android`, `BUILD` is SUCCESSFUL but I get error type 3 and I don't see that it installed on emulator.

This part of what I get when I run "react-native run-android" in cmd:

```
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2 mins 24.714 secs
Starting the app on ***** (...\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb -s **** shell am start -n app/.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=app/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {app/app.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

Comment: Which version of `react-native` are you using ? Did it occur after creating a new project or after upgrading `react-native` for an existing project ?

Comment: react-native version: 0.30.0, it is existing project, it was after updating project.

Comment: After shutdown the computer (windows 10), and open again,running again  "react-native run-android"  the application installed on emulator but still get this error "Error type 3
Error: Activity class {app/app.MainActivity} does not exist." I just opened application on emulator.

Comment: Are you sure there are both the files : `MainActivity.java` & `MainApplication.java` inside `android/app/src/main/java/com/appname` ? Can you please provide their code?

Comment: Yes, MainActivity.java & MainApplication.java inside android/app/src/main/java/com/appname/app

Comment: There were some issues after upgrading to latest version. This might help you : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8653

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Check whether the following files have the same package name say "com.companyName.appName":

```
1. package (usually line 2) in /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
2. applicationId (usually line 90) in defaultConfig section of /android/app/build.gradle
3. Line 1 of /android/app/src/main/java/com/paysack/MainApplication.java
4. Line 1 of /android/app/src/main/java/com/paysack/MainActivity.java
```

Step 2 :

```
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours on this and in the end I ended up replacing the package name. The original name contained 2 dots. E.g. `com.abc.test` Which I renamed to be `com.abctest` Also keep in mind to update the folder name in Android (`android/app/src/main/java/com`).

I also tried `react-native init myProject --package "com.abctest"` but seems like in recent versions of react native this no longer works.
I also tried using npm instead of yarn and I also tried to remove `node-modules` and `caches` but non of it worked.

Potentially you might also need to run
`watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf node_modules && npm install`
afterwards

I had this project working just fine a few weeks ago, but seems like something has changed somewhere and the `.` is no longer parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

shut down the emulator and start again then uninstalling the app from emulator solved my problem, if not then you  may need to restart your computer-good luck