# React-Native productFlavors (Error type 3: Activity class does not exist)

Tags: gradle, react-native, android-build-flavors

I want to use 2 `productFlavors` for my Android App: `live` and `staging`.

In `app/build.grandle` I defined them like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.some.id"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
splits {...}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }

    productFlavors {
        live {
            applicationId "com.some.id"
        }
        staging {
            applicationId "com.some.id.staging"
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I run `react-native run-android --variant=liveDebug` everything works just fine but when I try to run `react-native run-android --variant=stagingDebug` i get the error:

```
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 11.824 secs
Starting the app on 192.168.56.101:5555 (/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell am start -n com.somepackage/.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.somepackage/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.somepackage/com.somepackage.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

As the output says, the App was installed on the device but why does it say that `MainActivity` does not exist ? I guess it is due to the different applicationId although it is correct according to [this guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43736188/3163075

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue and I solve by adding the `appIdSuffix` to the `react-native` run command.

```
react-native run-android --variant variantDebug --appIdSuffix suffix
```

Comment: adding `--appIdSuffix=mySufix` worked well for me

Answer (score 12):

Add the `--appId` on run command, so the react native will know where to find the Main Activity:

`react-native run-android --variant=stagingDebug --appId com.some.id.staging`

Comment: for some reason, this doesn't work for me. I have an `applicationId` inside each `productFlavors`. It tries to start the activity of the wrong app id `react-native-cli: 2.0.1 - react-native: 0.59.8 - `

Answer (score 7):

Uninstall the app from the device using:

```
cd android && ./gradlew uninstallAll
```

Then run the app again using:

```
react-native start
react-native run-android
```

Comment: The command only uninstalled the app on devices but don't solve the problem at all

Answer (score 1):

There is a [pull request pending for React Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/8950) that will fix this issue.

Until then you can simply replace `/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js` with the [runAndroid.js file from the pull request](https://github.com/kgritesh/react-native/blob/1350b35c6f8d6fb55652734fe7a5923cae7be1fc/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js).

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `resValue` like this:

`staging {
          applicationId "com.some.id.staging"
          resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.some.id"
        }`

Comment: Where can I add resValue?

Answer (score 0):

Cause you change the applicationId in the `productFlavors`, `react-native-cli` can't recognize it. To fix, just add your changed appId when run start command

```
react-native run-android --variant=staging --appId com.some.id.staging
```