# React-Native: Error type 3: Activity class does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, react-native

I'm aware there's a plethora of questions/answers regarding this issue.  However, I have spent the past few days trying a number of solutions I've found on SO and none have worked thus far.

My error:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 52s
372 actionable tasks: 352 executed, 20 up-to-date
info Running C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
info Starting the app on emulator-5554 (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n mypackage/mypackage.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=mypackage/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {mypackage/mypackage.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

Here is a list of all the things I've attempted to do based on other SO posts:

**Attempts**

1. Running `adb kill-server`, `adb start-server`, then `react-native run-android`
2. Running `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`, then `react-native run-android` (a senior dev I used to work with told me the issue might be related to this a long time ago, but I cannot get in touch with him)
3. Uninstalling the App from the Emulator, as well as my physical device
4. `Build -> Clean Project`
5. `Files -> Invalidate Cache / Restart`
6. `Files -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`
7. `Build -> Rebuild Project`
8. Deleted gradle cache files in `/project/android/.gradle/5.1.1`
9. `AndroidManifest.xml` -> `<activity android:name=".MainActivity"` to `<activity android:name="packagename.MainActivity"`
10. `android/app/build.gradle` to view buildTypes

```
debug {
  applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
}
stagingRelease {
  applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
}
release {

}
```

Ran `react-native run-android --variant=[debug] --appIdSuffix '[.debug]'`

&&

Ran `react-native run-android --variant=[stagingRelease] --appIdSuffix '[.staging]'`

(these came with different errors)

11. Make sure android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "WHATEVER_THIS_IS" 
}
```

needs to match android/app/src/main/java/com/app_name/MainActivity.java line one:

```
package WHATEVER_THIS_IS;
```

needs to match android/app/src/main/java/com/app_name/MainApplication.java line one:

```
package WHATEVER_THIS_IS;
```

needs to match android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml line one:

```
package="WHATEVER_THIS_IS">
```

12. Went to `android/app/build.gradle` and changed:

```
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
}
```

to

```
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable true
        universalApk true  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
}
```

13. Went to `C:/Users/User/.gradle` to delete the `cache`.  Was unable to delete everything, as I kept getting alerts that many of the files/folders inside are currently "open in another program" (untrue as far as I can tell)

Nothing worked.

**Posts I followed for solutions**

[Error type 3 Error: Activity class {} does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist?page=3&tab=votes#tab-top)

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8653

["react-native run-android" - BUILD is SUCCESSFUL but get error type 3 Error: Activity class MainActivity does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202097/react-native-run-android-build-is-successful-but-get-error-type-3-error-act)

[Error type 3. Activity class {com.awesome_project/ com.awesome_project.MainActivity} does not exist in react native (Android device)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131769/error-type-3-activity-class-com-awesome-project-com-awesome-project-mainactiv)

Answer (score 16):

Even I was facing the same issue, and finally I found a solution.

1. Delete `app/build` directory.
2. cd into android and run `./gradlew uninstallAll` (ie, your device should be connected to your system).
   It started working after following the above steps.

Comment: for the 2 step: Windows environment to run .\gradlew uninstallAll.

Comment: I got the OPs error after uninstalling the App on my phone (through the phone). Trying to start the app multiple times didn't work, and gave no errors at first. The error appeared after a reboot of my dev computer. The steps in this answer solved it.

Comment: Didn't worked for me

Answer (score 9):

I Got The Error

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3m 10s 215 actionable tasks: 215 executed
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "EMAY8PU4VGAEN779"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.modernlaundaryforapk/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class
{com.modernlaundaryforapk/com.modernlaundaryforapk.MainActivity} does
not exist.
```

and here is the solution which worked for me

Open the `android/app/build.gradle` file in your project.

Locate the `defaultConfig` section within the file. Inside this section, you will find the `applicationId`

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myproject"
}
```

Now, open `android/app/src/main/java/com/app_name/MainActivity.java`  and check the first line

```
package com.myproject;
```

Make sure that `com.myproject` matches the `applicationId` value.

Similarly, verify that the package name in `AndroidManifest.xml` matches the `applicationId` value. Open the file located at `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and check the first line:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myproject">
```

Ensure that the package name `com.myproject` matches the `applicationId` value.

After verifying that all the package names are consistent, you can now attempt to run your React Native app using the following command:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

If the issue persists, you can try uninstalling the app from your device or emulator. Run the following command:

```
adb uninstall com.myproject
```

replace `com.myproject` with your actual `applicationId` value:

Then, rerun the command:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

This should resolve the issue, and your app should run correctly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: (RN 0.70+) After some debugging I found developers will get this error after they ***changed the `applicationId`***, due to easy setup rule the `applicationId` is your app default package name, and this package name is not only using in .java file, but other configs and even the folder structure (!). 
So you have to do a refactoring to move the files & replace all the occurrences to make sure they are using the new `applicationId`

Answer (score 5):

For those who might experienced the same situation like the one I faced!

Explanation:

*Note: I'm working on my app in eject mode*

I have updated my react-native npm package to the latest version (By the time of writing this answer **@0.67.2**). And then when I was staring (running) my android app in the emulator using (`npx react-native run-android`), I have experienced this error:

> Error type 3 - Error: Activity class {*.MainActivity} does not exist.

Solution which worked me:

1. In Android studio => Virtual device manager => I wiped user data (Please note the attached screenshot)
   [image]
2. In Visual studio, in the root of your project, locate android folder. delete build folder inside app folder. (please note the attached screenshot)
   [image]
3. run `npx react-native run-android` and you must be able to get your app running smoothly again.

Answer (score 4):

For RN projects try to run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Answer (score 4):

```
npx react-native run-android --variant devdebug --appIdSuffix dev
```

make sure your variant/appIdSuffix name is correct and match the above line

Comment: Jeez, Louise, wish I'd seen this answer before.. My solution / workaround was to run the app from Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps

1. Check if device is connected. Use command `adb devices`. If it shows your device than move to next step.
2. Run the command `adb uninstall com."app_name"`. If you get a `success` than move to next step.
3. Run the command `npx react-native run-android` inside the project root folder.

Answer (score 0):

For me it turned out I had the app installed in "Work" mode, I thought deleting it from "Personal" mode would fully delete it but apparently it didn't

Answer (score 0):

In my case, full package name in `android:name` property in `AndroidManifest.xml` caused this error. Going back to `.MainActivity` helped:

[image]